# Algorithm for generating restricted integer composition of N in k parts from interval [a,b] given the lexicographic number.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Consider the restricted compositions of $6$ in four parts from integers $\{1, 2, 3\}$.

```
 1     1     1     3

 1     1     2     2

 1     1     3     1

 1     2     1     2

 1     2     2     1

 1     3     1     1

 2     1     1     2

 2     1     2     1

 2     2     1     1

 3     1     1     1
```

Is it possible to generate single composition entry without listing all? For example if I provide the set ($n=6$ (the number), $k=4$ the number of partitions, $a=1$, $b=3$ which means that each partition must be between $a$ and $b$, inclusively, and $i=1$, meaning we're looking for the $i$-the lexicographically smallest composition entry) and it gives $[1, 1, 1, 3]$, the $1$-th entry from the list.

Similarly,
$(n=6, k=4, a=1, b=3, i=10)$ should return $[3, 1, 1, 1]$.

I searched the literature and found two algorithms but both of them enumerate all the possibilities at once.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27110-restricted-integer-composition

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44186-restricted-integer-compositions-with-fixed-number-of-parts/content/colex.m

Comment: Knuth's TAOCP vol. 4A deals with partitions, see if you can find something that suits the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the function $f(n, k, a, b, i)$ gives the $i$-th lexicographically smallest partition of $n$ into $k$ parts, each between $a$ and $b$, inclusively. I show how to compute $f$.

Let $g(n, k, a, b)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts, each between $a$ and $b$, inclusively. Clearly $g(n, k, a, b) = \sum_{a \le j \le b} g(n-j, k-1, a, b)$.

To compute $f$, first we try all the possible first entry of the partition. For each possible entry $a \le j \le b$, we know that there are $g(n-j, k-1, a, b)$ partitions of $n$ with $j$ as its first element. Thus, we will be able to know what is the first entry of the $i$-th partition by finding the smallest $j$ such that $\sum_{a \le k \le j} g(n-j, k-1, a, b) \ge i$. The entire partition is then $j$ appended with $f(n-j, k-1, a, b, i - \sum_{a \le z \le j-1} g(n-z, k-1, a, b))$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the recursive relation.

Comment: Though the relation $g(n, k, a, b) = \sum_{a \le j \le b} g(n-j, k-1, a, b)$ is correct for above problem, it breaks if the values of $a$ or $b$ are changed. For example if $a=2$, the relation changes to something like: $g(n, k, a, b) = \sum_{a \le j \le b} g(n-j-a, k-1, a, b)$.

Comment: @Galaxy Can you elaborate the last part? I don't really see how changing $a$ and $b$ breaks the formula. Even if $a=2$, the relation should still be $g(n, k, a, b) = \sum_{a \le j \le b} g(n-j, k-1, a, b)$, as it simply tries every possible first element ($j$).

Comment: I checked the relation be listing all the compositions:

Consider the number of partitions g(10,4,2,4) = 10
{     2     2     2     4,
     2     2     3     3,
     2     2     4     2,
     2     3     2     3,
     2     3     3     2,
     2     4     2     2,
     3     2     2     3,
     3     2     3     2,
     3     3     2     2,
     4     2     2     2}

However g(9,4,2,4) = 7, g(8,4,2,4) = 6, g(7,4,2,4) = 3
So the sums are not equal.

Comment: @Galaxy $g(10, 4, 2, 4) = g(10-2, 4-1, 2, 4) + g(10-3, 4-1, 2, 4) + g(10-4, 4-1, 2, 4)$?

Comment: OK, I see my mistake, Thanks again. Trying to understand the second part.

Comment: I tried but could not get the finding "smallest $j$" part right. I have written a small matlab program that correctly evaluates $g()$ but have problems with the "$f()$" vector. Is there way I can share it with you?

Comment: @Galaxy I'm not very comfortable with matlab, sorry :(, but I guess you should be able to do this with a while loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25857/discussion-between-galaxy-and-irvan).